# Manipulate domain to obtain a specific one

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have a function and I want to manipulate the domain, creating a g(x).

$f(x) = \log_{10}{(x+4)}$
       $Domain : \left(-4, +\infty\right)$

The domain that I want to obtain is 
$\left(-4, 3\right]$ using $g(f(x))$

I can't figure out the $g(x)$, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g(x)=\sqrt{\log_{10}7-x}$ then $g(f(x))=\sqrt{\log_{10}7-\log_{10}(x+4)}$